# how do i configure hpsmh to monitor multiple servers in a single console for HP servers

Tags: hp-service-manager

I installed HP SMH on one server and I am able to monitor that single server. But can I use the HP SMH tool to monitor multiple servers?

Comment: More likely to get an answer on serverfault

Comment: HP SMH is a freeware and can be used for single server.HP SIM is the tool not a freeware can be used to monitor multiple server

Answer (score 0):

HP SMH is a freeware and can be used for single server.HP SIM is the tool not a freeware can be used to monitor multiple server